# COM Components for Registration-Free Activation

Tags: com, interop, manifest, regfreecom

I have managed application (named managed.exe) that uses unmanaged assembly (named unmanaged.dll). Until now we've create Interop.unmanaged.dll, the managed.exe application had reference to the interop, and the unmanaged.dll was registered at the registry.
This worked fine.

Now I need to option to avoid the file in the registry and use private assembly (even though there is an older version still registered at the registry)

I found this article - [Configuring COM Components for Registration-Free Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x65a421a%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
I tried to create two manifests (both for the application and for the assembly), tried to put them as resource, but nothing worked.

Can anyone explain me the way to do so, step by step?
Including manifest examples?
Should I still work with the interop file as before?

I'll appreciate any tip...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these two walk-through articles:

(this link is temporarily dead)
[Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

[Registration-Free Activation of .NET-Based Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx)

Here's a better one I think:
"Registration-free COM components try-out" [Part1](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/06/registration-free-com-components.html) and [Part2](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.com/2009/06/registration-free-com-components_16.html)